# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Drawing.Common.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a .NET Core 3.1 WPF App its building successfully! But when I run a custom print function which is using System.Drawing it throw this error:

`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Drawing.Common.dll`

I even tried to install via NuGet:

[image]

App is building successfully but when I try to run the print function it throw error and print blank page.

**Funny thing is same codes are working with a console app**

> Below is detail about console app

[image]

[image]

> **Same Version Of System.Drawing.Common also not working**

**##Code For Print Function >>**

```
public static void Print()
        {
            PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
            p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
            {
                graphics = e1.Graphics;

                 Bitmap logo = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path, false);
            graphics.DrawImage(logo, new Point(25, (int)Offset));

            layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX + 75, startY + Offset + 25), layoutSize);
            graphics.DrawString("Receipt", font10, brush, layout, formatCenter);
    };
            try
            {
                p.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured While Printing \n" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the issue present/not present if you use the same version of System.Drawing.Common in both cases?

Comment: I tried same version as well not working

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: @Llama Added the codes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `path` in WPF version will not be found, see

`Bitmap.FromFile(path, false)`,

not the problem with System.Drawing.Common.dll

Ensure there is a file for `path`.